# Defining values across multiple modules in python

Tags: python, python-module

I have several different modules **all** with something like:

```
if not __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        logger = logging.getLogger()
    except:
        from MainApp.lib import setLogging
        logger = setLogging.initLogging("install.log")
else:
    from MainApp.lib import setLogging
    logger = setLogging.initLogging("install.log")
    setLogging.enableDebugLogging()
```

Is it possible to, say, define all of this at the __init__.py level?

Comment: I've found that I can run the sys.path stuff from within \__init__.py but it will only be called if the module is imported like `import lib.module` or `from lib import module` - direct imports fails. but the logger object does NOT get defined for the module.

Comment: ultimately I've decided against doing this.  While it isn't DRY these definitions will need to be made in the module itself to remain portable/unit-testable. I'd still love to know how to define an object at the \_\_init\_\_.py level - but I wont be watching this post.